# Reading word by word from Android Internal Storage

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

I'm working on an application that needs to write some data in a setting file and then read them from that file. I've done it with 4 different fileNames and 2 different for each file. Now I want to make one file and read data from those 4 other written Strings from that one file but I don't know how to find spaces or any other specific character when I'm reading data.

This is how I read data:

```
    public String read(String fileName) throws IOException{
    FileInputStream inStream = openFileInput(fileName);

    String content=null;
    byte[] readByte = new byte[inStream.available()];

    while(inStream.read(readByte) != -1)
        content = new String(readByte);

    inStream.close();
    return content;
}
```

And that's how I write:

```
    public void write(String fileName, String content) throws IOException{
    FileOutputStream outStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    outStream.write(content.getBytes());
    outStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a properties file as your setting file?

Comment: You can split a list of words separated by spaces, into a string array. Eg. `String content = "hello world !!!"; String[] words = content.split(" ");` and `words` will be equal with `["hello", "world", "!!!"]`. However, if you need to save small amount of info, then perhaps using `SharedPreferences` would be a better choice.

Comment: @AndyRes I don't really know how much data I want to store cuz I need to get a list of installed applications, want to save password and then lock my own app as well. Is `sharedPrefereces` a good option for saving passwords?

Comment: @Stephan I'm kinda' new to android. Didn't know anything about it. Thanks for your suggestion. properties file seems better.

Comment: SharedPrefs is not a good option for passwords, as the text is saved as plain text, no encryption.

Comment: @AndyRes What would you use instead? (If you encrypt the password, anyone who can read your SharedPrefs can also read your encryption key anyway)

Comment: I would suggest you take a look over this library https://facebook.github.io/conceal/. It's built by Facebook and provides fast cryptographic operations  for Android.